# Using Logback to set different colors for logging messages of different package

Tags: java, logback

I have just started using logback within Spring Boot for logging. And I have got a requirement for logging console based logs in a such a way that the log messages for different packages are written in different color depending upon which package the log belongs to.

here is my logback.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %logger{36} - %msg%n

            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Currently, what I m able to log messages for two different packages looks like this (same logged message color for every package) :
[image]

With some tweak I m able to achieve what I desire for, using the following logback.xml configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="console-root" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %logger{36} - %msg%n

            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console-p1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %logger{36} - %yellow(%msg%n)

            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console-p2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %logger{36} - %cyan(%msg%n)

            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="console-root" />
    </root>

    <logger name="com.rudra.logging.teacher" level="WARN" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="console-p1" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.rudra.logging.user" level="WARN" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="console-p2" />
    </logger>


</configuration>
```

As you can see in the image below that the log message from teacher package is logged in yellow color, whereas the log message from user package is in cyan color :
[image]

The second xml configuration helps me achieve the desired goal, but the main issue is that this requires a lot of boilerplate and as number of packages increases it will be cumbersome to maintain, also I feel using multiple appenders solely for this purpose isn't the right thing to do.

Comment: Last I checked, logging libraries don't have color code... Your terminal might (i.e. IntelliJ), but this is not portable, and shouldn't be relied upon .

Answer (score 0):

If you want all to be the same, you would use one appender. So, "your code" is cyan logs.

```xml
<appender name="root" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   <encoder>
        <pattern>
            %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %logger{36} - %cyan(%msg%n)
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="root" />
</root>
```

Then, you would only need one more appender to have classes in those packages (the "teachers") use a different color, like `yellow`.

```
<logger name="com.rudra.logging.teacher"
```

If you want external library logs in packages you don't control to have un-colored / different logs, then yes, you need 3 appenders.

Comment: As far as I understood from ur solution is that we will need different appenders for different colors (which I already know) but I am looking for a better solution, something which uses custom converter class or something similar to this.

Comment: Not that I know of. As mentioned in comment above, your terminal uses color codes, not Java, and not Logging libraries. Therefore putting "converter class" in the source code isn't really meaningful

Comment: And if were possible, would require you to alter the source-code of the teacher's code, which is against the point of slf4j and others